# Redux/ Layout container with props. Passing props from store to Layout using React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-router

I have a set of containers I've now separated out. Layout contains app navigation links. App contains the content within the Layout (effectively a child).

This is how the code looks when working without using a `Layout` with the navigation links.

```
export const App = hot(module)(() => (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={ Login } />
      <Route path="/csp" component={ CspApp } />
    </Switch>
    <ToastContainer transition={ Flip }/>
  </div>
));
```

This sits inside a `ReactDOM.render`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This all worked until I separated the layout from the base `CspApp`.

I've trying to add a Layout so it looks like this:

```
export const App = hot(module)(() => (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={ Login } />
      <Layout> <----- Expecting props
        <Route path="/csp" component={ CspApp } />
      </Layout>
    </Switch>
    <ToastContainer transition={ Flip }/>
  </div>
));
```

I believe this would work, but quite rightly, it's expecting the props for the top navigation to render correctly.

How do pass the props to this correctly? I could do it by passing the store into the component one by one:

```
  <Layout prop1={store.getState().prop1} action1={store.getState().action1}>
```

but is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to connect the layout [component to the store](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-container-components):

```
export default connect(stateToProps, dispatchToProps)(Layout);
```

You will have access to the store within your Layout component. If you need to pass some extra props to the Layout component you should do it on top the connected component as following:

```
<div>
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/login" component={ Login } />
  <Layout prop1="static-value" prop2={value}>
    <Route path="/csp" component={ CspApp } />
  </Layout>
</Switch>
<ToastContainer transition={ Flip }/>
</div>
```

**Update**: I see why you're confused, in the [new Redux-React site's docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components) I don't see the following pattern that was common and used often if you need to dispatch an Action with some props of the component:

```
const stateToProps = state => ({ stateProp2: state.someValue });
const dispatchToProps = (dispatch, { prop1, stateProp2 }) => ({
    doSomethingWithProp1: () => {
      console.log(prop1);
      dispatch({ type: 'SOME_ACTION', payload: stateProp2 }); // Take advantage of Layout's props also you can pass some props directly from state and get them here
    },
});

export default connect(stateToProps, dispatchToProps)(Layout);
```

You can get `doSomethingWithProp1()` function from `Layout` component's props and invoke it:

```
export class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Layout -- <button onClick={this.props.doSomethingWithProp1}>Click here</button></div>
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this, my actual issue is whether there's a shorthand way to write this, without passing everything independantly as `prop1`, `prop2` etc.

Comment: so pass all of them as `<Layout {...props} />`

Comment: The thing is, this container also contains Redux actions, which aren't contained in the store. Which means, I can't pass the action through `...props`.

Comment: Actions are bound by the second argument of `connect()` from redux. I don't understand why you're passing them via extra props.
Look at `mapDispatchToProps` within the link I included in the answer.